# Is there any program that can help me simulate a network with pingable devices?

Tags: networking, simulation, ping

I want a program that would help me create virtual devices on a virtual netowrk which you can manually turn on and off so that when you ping them from a program you can simulate a real device on a network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about "ping localhost"?
If you need other hostnames, you can do this in your host name table (**linux: /etc/hosts**)

Comment: Would this method allow me to change the devices states dynamically?

Comment: no this way forward all ping requests to your local machine. So have all "devices" same state as your computer

Answer (score 0):

Try to download and use  Vmware Player at http://www.vmware.com/products/player/.

Comment: How do I run multiple devices on VMware? I want to run 20 devices at the same time that respond to ping.